# Backtracking in DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Is it true that backtracking is allowed in deterministic finite automaton (as mentioned in many comparisons between DFA and NDFA)? If yes, how is it possible when transition in DFA is to a single state?

Comment: Please cite at least one such comparison.

Comment: It looks like you've copy-pasted the question from https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-backtracking-is-allowed-in-deterministic-finite-automaton-as-mentioned-in-many-comparisons-between-DFA-and-NDFA-If-yes-how-is-it-possible-when-transition-in-DFA-is-to-a-single-state, and then copy-pasted the answer below.  We're not looking for you to repeat questions from other sites; we want to generate useful new questions and answers that don't already have answers; and it's not very useful to ask questions where the answer is already available elsewhere and findable on Google.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your sources are here.  DFAs read the characters of the input one after another, strictly in order and accept or reject according to the state they're in when they reach the end of the word. There is no backtracking.